# Query to make 2 score equal teams

Tags: php, mysql, database, combinations

I have a table witch looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------
| index | players | date       | score |
----------------------------------------
|   1   | jan     | 2013-01-13 |   5   |
----------------------------------------
|   2   | piet    | 2013-01-13 |   6   |
----------------------------------------
|   3   | klaas   | 2013-01-13 |   5   |
----------------------------------------
|   4   | kees    | 2013-01-13 |   7   |
----------------------------------------
|   5   | william | 2013-01-13 |   8   |
----------------------------------------
|   6   | john    | 2013-01-13 |   4   |
----------------------------------------
```

Now I want to do something tricky, in order to play the next match like the match of 2013-01-14 we would like to make 2 score equal teams.

There are 12 players every date period so on 2013-01-13 are 12 players and on 2013-01-14 there are still the same players.

They have to be divorced into 2 teams so 12 / 2 = 6. 6 man in each team. Now that is not the problem the problem is that the total score of both teams has to be equal or close to each other.

If all the scores of the 12 players is 77 then the total scores of the 2 teams have to be almost equal like this 77 / 2 = 38,5

> team 1 - players 6 - total score 37
>
> team 2 - players 6 - total score 40

In the end the query output must be like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| index | players | date       | score | team |
-----------------------------------------------
|   1   | jan     | 2013-01-13 |   5   |   1  |
-----------------------------------------------
|   2   | piet    | 2013-01-13 |   6   |   1  |
-----------------------------------------------
|   3   | klaas   | 2013-01-13 |   8   |   1  |
-----------------------------------------------
|   4   | kees    | 2013-01-13 |   7   |   1  |
-----------------------------------------------
|   5   | william | 2013-01-13 |   5   |   1  |
-----------------------------------------------
|   6   | john    | 2013-01-13 |   6   |   1  |
-----------------------------------------------
|   7   | gerrit  | 2013-01-13 |   6   |   2  |
-----------------------------------------------
|   8   | maartje | 2013-01-13 |   6   |   2  |
-----------------------------------------------
|   9   | shara   | 2013-01-13 |   8   |   2  |
-----------------------------------------------
|  10   | els     | 2013-01-13 |   7   |   2  |
-----------------------------------------------
|  11   | allen   | 2013-01-13 |   5   |   2  |
-----------------------------------------------
|  12   | steven  | 2013-01-13 |   8   |   2  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

and

```
-----------------------------------------------
|  team     | score    | date       | players |
-----------------------------------------------
|  Team 1   | 37       | 2013-01-13 |    6    |
-----------------------------------------------
|  Team 2   | 40       | 2013-01-13 |    6    |
-----------------------------------------------
```

With some inspiration of #Danack I made this:

```
$difference = 10;
$team_smnstlln = array();
for($q=0; $q<1000; $q++){
    
    $players = array();
    
    $team_smnstlln[$q] = array(
                                'team1' => array(),
                                'team2' => array(),
                                'total' => 0
                              );
    
    $count1 = 0;
    for($w=0; $w<6; $w++){
        $player = pick_random(true);
        $score1 = $team_smnstlln[$q]['team1'][$player] = $data[$player]['score'];
        $count1 = $count1 + $score1;
    }
    
    $count2 = 0;
    for($w=6; $w<12; $w++){
        $player = pick_random(true);
        $score2 = $team_smnstlln[$q]['team2'][$player] = $data[$player]['score'];
        $count2 = $count2 + $score2;
    }
    
    if($count1 > $count2){
        $total = $count1 - $count2;
    }
    elseif($count2 > $count1){
        $total = $count2 - $count1;
    }
    else{
        $total = 0;
    }
    
    $team_smnstlln[$q]['total'] = $total;
    
    if($team_smnstlln[$q]['total'] == 0){
        $difference = 0;
        $winner = $q;
        break;
    }
    elseif($team_smnstlln[$q]['total'] < $difference){
        $difference = $team_smnstlln[$q]['total'];
        $winner = $q;
    }
    
}

echo "Kleinst gekozen set met score verschil van $difference punten. array $winner is gekozen<br>";

$team1 = $team_smnstlln[$winner]['team1'];
$team2 = $team_smnstlln[$winner]['team2'];

print_r($team1);
print_r($team2);

// random player picker

function pick_random($gonogo){
    
    global $players;
    
    $go = true;
    $total_players = 11;
    
    while($go){
        
        $player = rand(0, $total_players);
        
        if(!in_array($player, $players)){
            $players[] = $player;
            $go = false;
        }
        
    }
    
    return $player;
    
}
```

This code runs 1000 diffrent team set ups. when a score difference of 0 is reacht it will stop en echo the best equal teams match. Or else when there is no 0 difference it will give back the lowest outcome

Comment: Fetch the whole thing and do it in PHP, it would be easier.

Comment: Oké but how do I do this in php. I am working on the theory but I stuck. this is how far I came: 1 - divide the total player with 2(make 2 teams) 2 - count up the total score and divide with 2. 3 - make team one and when counter of score meets up to the half total score stop and make team 2. then I stuck with the problem that it will never be 50% vs 50%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As moonwave99 said, doing this in PHP is a much better idea than trying to do it in SQL.

The issue is that this is a hard problem to solve. You can see that by re-asking your question as:

"What combination of 6 players in 1 team, and 6 players in the other team, will have the smallest difference in scores?"

The number of combinations for picking 6 players out of 12 is (12! / 6!) or 665,280 combinations, each of which would need to have the difference in scores calculated.

You would need to go through all the combinations possible, and calculate the score of each combination to find the 'best' combination.

```
//An array to record whether each player has already been selected for a combination
$playersChosen = array();

//Initialise the array
for($x=0 ; $x<12 ; $x++){
    $playersChosen[$x] = FALSE;
}

//Need to store lowest score somewhere - and have a flag for the first calculation
$lowestScore = FALSE;


chooseAnotherPlayer(6, 0);

//$GLOBALS['bestCombination'] - will now contain the best combination of players.


//Recursive function that either:
//goes through each player in turn and then calls itself or 
//calculates the 'score' when all the players are chosen for one team
//$playersToChoose - how many players left to choose.
//$minimumPlayerNumber - index to start searching for players not yet chosen - as the choice,  3 + 5 is identical to 5 + 3
function chooseAnotherPlayer($playersToChoose, $minimumPlayerNumber){

    //We have 6 pl
    if($playersToChoose == 0){
        //Calculate Score from which players are selected in $GLOBALS['playersChosen']
        if($lowestScore === FALSE ||
            $score < $lowestScore){
            $GLOBALS['bestCombination'] = $GLOBALS['playersChosen'];  //Arrays are copied by value, not reference
//So this saves a snapshot of the best selection.
        }
        return;
    }

    //Go through each of the players
    for($x=$minimumPlayerNumber ; $x<12; $x++){
        //Select them if they're available
        $playerAvailable = selectPlayer($x);
        if($playerAvailable == TRUE){
                    //Pick another player
            chooseAnotherPlayer($playersToChose - 1, $x + 1);
                    //Release this player, so he's available for other combinations
            unselectPlayer($x);
        }
    }
}

function selectPlayer($x){
    if($GLOBALS['playersChosen'][$x] == TRUE){
        //Player has already been selected in this combination.
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

If you don't mind that taking a few seconds to process that code will solve your problem exactly. However if you need it to be quick, you would be better off just selecting the teams at random, evaluate the 'score' and do enough iterations to have a reasonable result.

```
$playersChosen = array();

resetArray();

$playersToChose = 6;
$lowestScore = FALSE;

for($n=0 ; $n<10000 ; $n++){
    chooseAnotherPlayers(6);
    resetArray();
}

function chooseAnotherPlayer($playersToChoose){

    if($playersToChoose == 0){
        //Calculate Score from which players are selected in $GLOBALS['playersChosen']
        if($lowestScore === FALSE ||
            $score < $lowestScore){
            $GLOBALS['bestCombination'] = $GLOBALS['playersChosen'];
            return;
        }
    }

    selectPlayerAtRandom($x);
    chooseAnotherPlayer($playersToChose - 1);
}

function selectPlayer($x){

    $playerSelected = FALSE;

    while($playerSelected == FALSE){

        $x = rand(0, 12 - 1);

        if($GLOBALS['playersChosen'][$x] == FALSE){
            $GLOBALS['playersChosen'][$x] = TRUE;
            return $x;
        }    
    }

}

function resetArray(){
    for($x=0 ; $x<12 ; $x++){
        $GLOBALS['playersChosen'][$x] = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Unless you need to have the teams precisely matched, this will likely give you very close results even after only covering a small percentage of the different combinations, due to the maths behind standard deviations and distribution.

You could make the function even smarter by figuring out by 'rule of thumb' what an acceptable total score difference would be, and searching until either you find one combination of players that meets that criteria or a maximum search time is run (possibly generating an alert that the search timed out, and the matchup is uneven).

Comment: I will take a look into this. right now I just loop till the half score is not bigger than the score counter. I edit my question with my own code just in a minute.

Comment: For a bit of further reading, your problem basically boils down to the Knapsack Problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do in SQL, and doing it in the database has certain advantages -- notably, the database can take advantage of parallelism.  The following gets 6 team members on one of the teams.  The rest should be easy to figure out:

```
select t1.index, t2.index, t3.index, t4.index, t5.index, t6.index,
       (t1.score+t2.score+t3.score+t4.score+t5.score+t6.score) as TeamScore
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.index < t2.index join
     t t3
     on t2.index < t3.index join
     t t4
     on t3.index < t4.index join
     t t5
     on t4.index < t5.index join
     t t6
     on t5.index < t6.index cross join
     (select cast(sum(score)/2 as integer) as score from t) as Half
where Half.Score - TeamScore in (0, 1)
order by (Half.score - TeamScore)
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Fire the following query, it will put 6 records in team 1

```
 update table1 t1 set t1.team="1" where id IN(
    SELECT y.id
      FROM (SELECT t.id,
                   t.scores,
                   (SELECT SUM(x.scores)
                      FROM table1 x
                     WHERE x.id <= t.id) AS running_total
             FROM table1 t
         ORDER BY t.id) y
     WHERE y.running_total > (select * from (SELECT SUM(scores)/2 FROM table1) as sum) 
    ORDER BY y.id);
```

Now below query will put other 6 records in team 2

```
update table1 t1 set t1.team="2" where id NOT IN(
    SELECT y.id
      FROM (SELECT t.id,
                   t.scores,
                   (SELECT SUM(x.scores)
                      FROM table1 x
                     WHERE x.id <= t.id) AS running_total
             FROM table1 t
         ORDER BY t.id) y
     WHERE y.running_total > (select * from (SELECT SUM(scores)/2 FROM table1) as sum) 
    ORDER BY y.id);
```